# Remove Quotation mark from in between of the String but from 0th index and -1th index

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to remove quotation mark from this string:

```
'"Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter """"""""""""""""Spark 2, sparkCSV parser"""""""""""""""" - DDSAD"""""""""""'
```

Output should be

```
'"Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter Spark 2, sparkCSV parser - DDSAD"'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Take the string and replace the `'"'` with `''`; then place them back in `'""'` with `'"{}"'.format`:

```
s = '"Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter """"""""""""""""Spark 2, sparkCSV parser"""""""""""""""" - DDSAD"""""""""""'
r = '"{}"'.format(s.replace('"', ''))
```

Result being:

```
'"Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter Spark 2, sparkCSV parser - DDSAD"'
```

For your larger string as supplied in the comment, you could `split` on the `comma` and *then* join the formatted strings on the comma again:

```
s = '"EM16203120","Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter """"""""""""""""Spark 2, sparkCSV parser"""""""""""""""" - DDSAD"""""""""""'
r = ','.join('"{}"'.format(sb.replace('"', '')) for sb in s.split(','))
```

With `r` now being:

```
'"EM16203120","Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter Spark 2"," sparkCSV parser - DDSAD"'
```

Comment: Works fine Thanks Jim.

Comment: What if i have `'"EM16203120","Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter """"""""""""""""Spark 2, sparkCSV parser"""""""""""""""" - DDSAD"""""""""""'` and i want op as `'”EM16203120”, "Hello World - October 1 Not Trending Twitter Spark 2, sparkCSV parser - DDSAD"'`

Comment: I see @Scarecrow, I updated the answer to include a solution for that.